# Why does my button click listener not work in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await

I'm trying to create a chrome extension, my problem is that when I try to place an event listener to each button in a class, only the first button has one, and the rest don't have an event listener.

```
function copyButtonInitialise(){
    var copyButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("copyPassword");
    console.log("length = ", copyButtons.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < copyButtons.length; i++){
        console.log(copyButtons[i] + " element number " + i + "= button");
        copyButtons[i].addEventListener("click", copyButtonClick);
    } 
}
```

This function is what should be called if any button with the class "copyPasword" is clicked.(just want to make sure it gets clicked, but it doesn't)

```
 function copyButtonClick(){
        console.log("Hello There");
    }
```

This is the function that loads passwords, it's called before adding event listeners to buttons.

```
async function loadPasswords(){
    document.getElementById("passwordTable").innerHTML = "";
    console.log("This is the loadpasswords function");
    chrome.storage.sync.get(null, function(items) {
        var allKeys = Object.keys(items);
        
        var passwordTable = document.getElementById("passwordTable");
        var header = passwordTable.createTHead();
        var passwordRow = header.insertRow(0);
        
        for(var i = 0; i < allKeys.length; i++){
            let passwordKey = allKeys[i];
            chrome.storage.sync.get([allKeys[i]], function(value){
                var passwordName = Object.keys(value);
                passwordName = passwordName[0];
                var table = document.getElementById("passwordTable");
                var header = table.createTHead();
                var passwordRow = header.insertRow(0);
                var cellTwo = passwordRow.insertCell(0);
                var cell = passwordRow.insertCell(1);
                cellTwo.innerHTML = "<p1 id=passwordNameCol>" + passwordName + "</p1>";
                cell.innerHTML = "<button class=copyPassword> Copy " + '"'+ passwordName + '"'+ "</button>";
                
            });
        }
    });
}
```

The passwords clearly load in.
[image: passwords]

When I click the buttons, nothing gets sent to the console, expecting a "hello there" (as shown above)
[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these things:

1. the outer **chrome.storage.sync.get(null**  returns all stored couples key+value.
   Why you use chrome.storage.sync.get a second time inside the "for" statement? It is not necessary.
2. Don't use insert methods of table but try with createElement and appendChild.
   Create first an THEAD (or TBODY) element and then put every rows on it.
   When you'll finish you'll have to append only that THEAD\TBODY as child of your table.
3. Try to create the button with createElement (as i suggest for any other table elements) and after its creation put the event listener on it (inside the "for").
4. if you think to reuse the same table for other differente rows remenber to destroy the THEAD first otherwise the just created events listeners will remain orphans.
   Destroy the THEAD with something like **element.remove()** and not with **innerHTML = ""**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, all your points were useful, especially 3 as that helped solve my problem!